# Fscanf incrementing file position pointer wierdly

Tags: c, pointers

This is the part of the code that's working as not as intended (well at least as I was expecting too).

```
 fscanf(**readFile,"%d", buffer.head);
```

`**readFile` is a pointer-to-pointer pointing to the file I've opened. In the file there are numbers written one below another like this:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

What is weird is that when I print out position of the file pointer with :

```
 printf("Position %ld", ftell(**readFile));
```

I'm getting odd numbers : `1 3 5...` which means every time I run  `fscanf(**readFile,"%d", buffer.head);` in a loop, file pointer will not be pointing to next number (e.g. 2), rather it will point to 3rd number(3). I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: So readFile is a (File **)?

Comment: Maybe show some more of the relevant code?

Comment: Isn't it odd to declare `FILE` pointer like that ?

Comment: It's a pointer declared as local variable in main passed to a function that creates a thread running this part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

File positions are in bytes. You don't specify the exact format of your text file, but assuming single-byte line termination (on e.g. Unix or Linux) and blank lines between each line like you showed, three bytes per number seems to make sense for the first 9:

Basically the format of your file seems to be:

```
1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n...
```

If you're on Windows, and the blank lines are a mistake, the structure would instead be:

```
1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n...
```

And it's still three bytes per number for the first 9.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i edited numbers how they are stored in .txt file.

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot As I tried to explain above, that's because the position is in *bytes*, and there is whitespace between the numbers.

Comment: Problem was that i was overwriting memory of the buffer because fscanf is storing nul terminator, now i need to find how to store integer without nul terminator

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot What? No? There'¨s no "nul terminator" with an integer... Are you not handing `fscanf()` a proper `int *` argument? It's hard to know what `buffer.head` is, but it should be a properly initialized `int *` of course.

Comment: Well, somehow `fscanf` is storing newline character into the next place in the buffer which leads to overflow after 5 inputs.